# It's Not Good To Use Too Much of Me

Tags: riddle

Here's my first ordinary riddle :

> You can look at me for a really long time, even for hours, without getting bored
>
> And I get more and more hot as time goes by
>
> Yet once the power is cut off
>
> You do not even pay the slightest attention to me
>
> As if I am just a useless object
>
> Many say that I am not a good influence, especially to youngsters
>
> But in almost every home, I will always be there

Comment: I'm not really good at coming up with normal riddles so feedbacks and suggestions are welcome :))

Comment: It's good to try something new. You have made many nice riley riddles, and now you are attempting at some ordinary riddles. I have never written an ordinary riddle (yet), as I always like to incorporate a bit of rhyme and poetry in mine (as well as some originality to make my riddle different and unique) :)

Comment: Lol. I guess you should try making one too @user477343

Comment: @user477343 your anagram riddles are pretty good, haven't gotten those for a while

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid thank you. I'm trying to make more but can't seem to make some other anagrams. I was thinking, for example: *The man did not* ***desire*** to ***reside*** *in such a small apartment.* But I am running out of other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is-

> Television (TV)

Explanation

> you can stare at it for hours, but not when the power is off, parents sometime complain it being not a good influence,but almost every house has one.

Comment: Yep correct answer. Gonna accept in 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Laptop/Computer

You can look at me for a really long time, even for hours, without getting bored

> Being connected to the internet is addictive.

And I get more and more hot as time goes by

> Laptops and computers tend to heat up over time.

Yet once the power is cut off

You do not even pay the slightest attention to me

> Laptops and computers lose their use when they are powered off.

As if I am just a useless object

> Fair

Many say that I am not a good influence, especially to youngsters

> People say youngsters spend too much time in front of a screen which is not good for them.

But in almost every home, I will always be there

> Laptops and computers are ubiquitous.

Comment: Nope. But you are quite near as the answer is also an electronic device